# excel vba replace dialog (ctrl+h) line break

Tags: vba, replace, newline, line-breaks

When I'm in VBA and clicking CTRL+H to replace, i want to find a string and replace it with same string + break line + other string

I know how to add break line in CTRL+H in Excel (CTRL+J), VBA CTRL+H is different.

I know how to add break line in a function in Excel (CHAR(10)), VBA CTRL+H is different.

I know how to add break line in a MsgBox in VBA (vbCrLf), VBA CTRL+H is different.

```
Dim i, xa, xb, counter As Integer

counter = 0

For i = 1 To 5
    If Cells(i, 1) = "a" Then
      xa = i
    ElseIf Cells(i, 1) = "b" Then
      xb = i
    End If
Next i
```

in the example code i added I want to replace "= i" with "= i + new line + counter = counter + 1"

this is just an example code, my real code has many more ElseIf and I want to do it quickly without making a mistake manually.

this picture sums up my exact problem:
[image: this picture sums up my exact problem:]

Comment: a line break in VBA is `vbCrLf`

Comment: I edited my post and added a picture. See how vbCrLf not working.

Comment: Ahh I see what you're doing now - try `= i^p counter = counter + 1`. If that doesn't work, you can just do `= i: counter = counter + 1` - it would be on one line, but have the same effect.

Comment: I will try that, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VBA Editor that is buit into Excel, Acces, etc. is **not capable** of Multiline Search (and Replace). Perhaps you can have some kind of an extension installed, e.g. "Helixoft", or you can programmatically manipulation of the code using VBA itself, as it is explained in every detail in this: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx. Good luck!